# Style option tag HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to style my option tag. I want to set its height and its padding but it doesn't work. I tried to change option's background and this worked well but the height and the padding don't. Here is my HTML code:

```
  <select id="from_currency" >
    <option value="AED">AED</option>
    <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
    <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
    <option value="BGN">BGN</option>
    <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
  </select>
```

And CSS:

```
 option{ 
 padding:20px;
 height:40px;
 }
```

But these styles doesn't work.

Comment: The option element, and select elements are not really good at taking styles. There are a lot of libraries that simulate their behavior using more styleable elements. [Further Reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is limited styling capability for `<option>`, as this element is an Operating System element. For better styling of `<option>` use plugins. [For example this plugin](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage) (jquery is required). But you can style the selected element in this way - `option[selected]`. I have provided some examples of how you can style your `<option>`. Perhaps these are not all possible options.

```css
 #from_currency{ 
   background-color: blue;
   color: green;
 }
 
 #from_currency2{ 
   font-size: 120%;
   width: 100%;
 }
 
 #from_currency3 option[selected]{ 
   background-color: green;
 }
```

```html
<select id="from_currency" >
    <option value="AED">AED</option>
    <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
    <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
    <option value="BGN">BGN</option>
    <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
</select>

<select id="from_currency2" >
    <option value="AED">AED</option>
    <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
    <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
    <option value="BGN">BGN</option>
    <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
</select>

<select id="from_currency3" >
    <option value="AED">AED</option>
    <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
    <option value="AUD" selected>AUD</option>
    <option value="BGN">BGN</option>
    <option value="BRL">BRL</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to your options like this:

```html
  <select id="from_currency" >
    <option class="option" value="AED">AED</option>
    <option class="option" value="ARS">ARS</option>
    <option class="option" value="AUD">AUD</option>
    <option class="option" value="BGN">BGN</option>
    <option class="option" value="BRL">BRL</option>
  </select>
```

and then in the css file do it like this

```css
 .option{ 
 padding:20px;
 height:40px;
 }
```

**In case that didn't work**
Make sure that you linked your CSS file correctly to your HTML file like this. And you won't need to add classes

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style the  or  tags with CSS. The only change that you can do with CSS is with Colors.

You have two options:

1 - You'll have to build your own custom dropdown using  or similar tags.

2 - Use a library that allows you to create custom dropdowns with ease and provide you with extra events.

One good library is this: [Select2](https://select2.org/)

There are multiple other options available. You'll have to select the best one based on the tech/framework you're using.